# how do I move Ubuntu from the desk and save it to my harddrive?

Tags: 20.04

I have a 4TB hard drive but I don't know how to put Ubuntu on my hard drive.

Comment: If asking to install see this link.  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu). If not, then please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1296780/edit) to be more specific about which parts of the "move" you need help with or do not understand.